# Preload Key requests issue

Tags: php, wordpress, preload, pagespeed-insights

Currently, I am using WordPress and I am finding Google Page speed insights reporting the following issues:

[image: Preload keyrequests]

However, in my `functions.php` I have the following code:

```php
add_filter( 'genesis_before_header', 'orh_header_html' );
function orh_header_html() {

    ?>

<!--Adding Fontawesome-->
<link rel="preload" href="/wp-content/themes/genesis-child/fontawesome/css/all.css" as="style">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/genesis-child/fontawesome/css/all.css">
<!--Adding fonts-->
<link rel="preload" href="/wp-content/themes/genesis-child/fonts/gibson/style.css" as="style">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/genesis-child/fonts/gibson/style.css">
<link rel="preload" href="/wp-content/themes/genesis-child/fonts/opensans/style.css" as="style">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/genesis-child/fonts/opensans/style.css">

<?php
}
```

And a function to add `preload` for the missed ones.

```php
//Preload
function add_rel_preload($html, $handle, $href, $media) {
    
    if (is_admin())
        return $html;

     $html = <<<EOT
<link rel='preload' as='style' onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'" id='$handle' href='$href' type='text/css' media='all' />
EOT;
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'add_rel_preload', 10, 4 );
```

What could be the reason that Google pagespeed insights still asking me to include `preload`? And How can I fix this?

Comment: None of the items you listed above in your code example correspond to the missing items on the report? Also it appears you are preloading `adservice.google...` but not using it. See if the fonts etc. are linked within other CSS files as that won't get picked up automatically and you will have to manually add the preload for them.

Comment: Thank you @GrahamRitchie I was able to figure it out.